# VHDL bit rotation function syntax error?

Tags: function, vhdl, hdl

I am doing this for my school work where I'm making my own rolling/shifting function.
Below is the code I wrote, but when i try to compile it i get syntax error on rownum<=rol(rowcount,1);

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

architecture main of proj is

function "rol" (a: std_logic_vector; n : natural)
                return std_logic_vector is
begin
return std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) rol n);
end function;

signal rownum : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal rowcount : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);

begin

process begin
wait until rising_edge(i_clock);
**rownum<=rol(rowcount,1);**

end process;

end architecture main;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that need to be addressed here.

Firstly, you need an entity statement:

```
entity  proj is
    port(
    i_clock : in std_logic
    );
end  proj;
```

This declares what signals are inputs and outputs for your entity. In this case, it's just a clock. You can add rownum and rowcount inputs and outputs too as needed.

Your function name shouldn't be in inverted commas, and overloading an existing operator isn't a good idea either.

```
function rol_custom (a: std_logic_vector; n : natural)
            return std_logic_vector is
begin
return std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) rol n);
end function;
```

Here's the synthesizable code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity  proj is
    port(
    i_clock : in std_logic
    );
end  proj;

architecture main of proj is

function rol_custom (a: std_logic_vector; n : natural)
                return std_logic_vector is
begin
return std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) rol n);
end function;

signal rownum : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal rowcount : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);

begin

process begin
wait until rising_edge(i_clock);
rownum<=rol_custom(rowcount,1);

end process;

end architecture main;
```

However, even though this now should synthesize, the results won't make any sense, because rowcount has not been given a value. In order to define it, you might want to add a process which drives the signal based on certain criteria (a counter?) or add it as an input in the entity definition.

Answer (score 0):

If your vectors represent numbers, you should use a numerical type for them.  Use the `ieee.numeric_std` library and a `unsigned` or `signed` type as appropriate.  `rol` will then just work.  You won't have to create your own.